# How can I make my html embed (js) visible on different tabs?

Tags: javascript, webflow

I have built a vertical tab dropdown and in each tab, I have Html embed (javascript). I only put code into my html embed so there is no code on the page site. Maybe this could be an issue why it does not work.  However it only shows on the first tab and the rest are not there. Do you know how I can make it work? Attached you see my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="mychart2" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("mychart2");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            const decimals = 0;
            var config = {              //configure the chart
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['0', '1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9+'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "25th Percentile",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
                        pointBackgroundColor:"#645bff",
                        borderColor: '#645bff',
                        fill: 4,
                        pointRadius:0,
                        pointBorderWidth:3,
                        pointHoverRadius:3,
                        pointHitRadius:3,//no fill here
                        data: [28, 35, 40, 45,50,55,62,66,70,78]
                    },{
                        label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
                        backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
                        pointBackgroundColor:"#c4c1ff",
                        borderColor: '#c4c1ff',
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor:"#c4c1ff",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
                        borderWidth:1,
                        pointRadius:0,
                        pointBorderWidth:3,
                        pointHoverRadius:3,
                        pointHitRadius:3,
                        fill: 3, 
                        //no fill here
                        data: [40, 65, 63, 64,72,79,83,87,100,108]
                    },{
                        label: "Median",
                        backgroundColor: '#0d0e25',
                        pointBackgroundColor:"#0d0e25",
                        borderColor: '#0d0e25',
                        borderWidth:1,
                        pointRadius:2,
                        pointBorderWidth:3,
                        pointHoverRadius:3,
                        pointHitRadius:3,
                        fill: false,  //no fill here
                        data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 56, 60, 66,73 ,78,85]},
                    {
                        label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
                        tooltipTitle:"75th Percentile",
                        showInLegend: false,
                        backgroundColor: '#645bff',
                        pointBackgroundColor:"#645bff",
                        borderColor: '#645bff',
                        pointRadius:0,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        pointBorderWidth:3,
                        pointHoverRadius:3,
                        pointHitRadius:3,
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                                        borderDash: [],
                                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        fill:0 ,
                        //fill until previous dataset
                        data: [35, 50, 51, 55,63,69,73,80,85,94]
                    },{
                        label: "10th Percentile",
                        backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
                        pointBackgroundColor:"#c4c1ff",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor:"#c4c1ff",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
                        borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
                        pointStyle:"circle",
                        borderWidth:1,
                        lineWidth:1,
                        hoverRadius:9,
                        pointRadius:0,
                        pointBorderWidth:3,
                        pointHoverRadius:3,
                        pointHitRadius:3,
                        lineTension:0.3,
                       
                        fill: '0', //fill until previous dataset
                        data: [25, 30, 36, 39, 45, 49, 53,56,60,68]
                    }]
                },
                options: {
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
            if (label) {
              label += ': ';
            }
            if (label === "25th - 75th Percentile: ") {
              label = "75th Percentile: "
            }
            label += tooltipItem.yLabel
            return label;
          }
        }
      },title: {display:true, text: 'Frontend Engineer salaries (753 datapoints)',fontSize:20},
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),display:true, labels: {filter:function(item,
                    mychart2)
                    {return !item.text.includes("10th - 90th Percentile" & "10th Percentile");}}},
                    spanGaps: false,
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                            tension: 0.000001
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        filler: {
                            propagate: false
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{gridLines: {display:false}, scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Salary', 
                        fontSize:20},
                            ticks: {beginAtZero:true, stepSize: 20,callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value.toFixed(decimals)}
                            }
                        }], xAxes: [{gridLines: {display:false},
                            ticks: {beginAtZero:true, stepSize: 20,
                                
                            }, scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: 'Years of relevant experience',
                     fontSize: 20 }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            };
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
        </script>
```

Comment: I solved the problem by myself. Make sure that you put a div block in the canvas and then ensure that each gets a seperate ID.